# I chopped through 1/3 of the width of the cord leading to my angle grinder - it still works should I replace the cord?

Tags: electrical

I had an angle grinder setup in a chopsaw stand.  Something similar to this:

[https://www.amazon.com/RO-LY-100-125-Grinder-Support/dp/B07NTXMHC1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07NTXMHC1)

It was the first time using the setup and I didn't notice that the cord came into the area of the grinder disc.  I cut through ~1/3 of the strands of copper in the cord.  The grinder still seems to be working.  I put electrical tape around the cut area.

Do I need to replace the cord?  If I don't replace the cord what are the downsides, the grinder is fairly cheap.

Comment: If its a cheap grinder, now might be the right time to invest in a battery powered angle grinder rather than go through the hassle of replacing or repairing the cord.

Comment: Do you?   No.   Could it just stop working whenever?   Yes.   Is it dangerous?   Not if insulated and you have already taped it.   On nicked cords I use electrical tape then 2-3 short individual strands of duct tape.   This provides something flexible that will give it some weatherproofing.

Comment: With some of the strands gone, it'll be a hotspot on the wire. Being cheap Chinese bought via Amazon, it has bypassed all the controls that force domestic sellers to sell UL-listed equipment that is certified to safety standards.  The cord won't be the correct self-extinguishing non-poison-smoke-emitting plastic, so just put it out right away.  Also, it might electrocute you so wear lineman's gloves.  Try not to have your cheap Chinese lineman's gloves also catch fire when trying to put out the cord fire.  *Shrug... the important thing is the savings. What could possibly go wrong?*

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - if he is lucky the electricity won't matter because of those well insulated chinese made boots.   13 year olds make the best boots.

Comment: @statueuphemism I have a makita cordless - seems very under powered compared to even $30 4.5" grinders.  What cordless grinder do you recommend?  I have at least 6 grinders 9, 7.5, 5, and a few 4.5" corded only the makita cordless.

Comment: I have at least 6 as well, but only on two of them would I replace the cord. "the grinder is fairly cheap" - steal the nuts, wrench, handle, and what's left of the plug; throw the rest of it away.

Comment: @FreshCodemonger Never thought power was a huge factor with angle grinders since applying pressure doesn’t really help cut much faster but increases premature wear on the wheel (unless we’re talking raw rpms or disc size). I’ve been very happy with a relatively cheap $45 5” brushed battery-powered Hitachi for cutting cast iron pipe and galvanized fasteners on my car. That said, if you’ve got a setup you’re happy with, then keep at it.

Comment: @statueuphemism It just seems like with the cordless that putting pressure against the disc to cut something causes it to visibly slow down where as the same pressure with a corded doesn't cause the disc to slow.  The speed to cut through something letting the tool do the work also seems at least twice as slow.  I'll use the cordless to deburr or clean up cuts but it is painful to do larger tasks.

Comment: ***"I plan to electrocute myself, is this a good way to go about it?"***

Comment: You NEVER want to accept compromised power cables.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, replace the cord.

Seen too many damaged cords covered in unravelling sticky tape that then become dangerous - wet environment, spilled liquid etc etc

Adding a cable joiner just adds a "catching" or "trapping" hazard.

2 or 3 metres (6 or 9 feet for some) of quality cable is cheap and safer.

Also the length of cable is likely to be cheaper than a fancy repair plug...

Comment: I've used the repair plugs to turn 100' extension cords into multiple shorter cords when the ground pin eventually breaks.  I could probably find some quality cable but won't I still need to put a repair plug on the quality cable?

Comment: Yes you will need a repair male plug. That is the simpliest/easiest way to repair it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes - replace the cord, or shorten it and fit a new plug at the cut.

Assuming you've cut 1/3 of the strands, and it is an earthed appliance with 3 wires in the cord, and it still works, then you've cut ~1/2 of the strands in two wires.

If you've cut 1/3 of the strands in a 2 wire cord then ~1/3 of each is cut.

This **reduces the current carrying capacity of the wire by more than half** resulting in localised heating. Which will soften any adhesive and some of them can conduct when liquid.

---

If you're not able to see why your tape-repair is inadequate, then replacing the whole tool is the better option over replacing or shortening the cord.

Comment: First time I've cut through a cord though I frequently see others using electrical taped cords on circular saws.  It has a ground pin.  I didn't look too closely at the damaged part of the cord but I assume if I had cut into two of the conductors in the cord it would short rather than turn on.  Possible out of the three wires in the cord I only cut through the ground...  I'll have a better look but it seems like no one is in the if it works keep using it camp so I'll just chuck it on the to repair pile.

Comment: @FreshCodemongery you have done well to notice and to ask.   If you happend to cut the ground wire and the tool still works, its now totally unsafe and absolutely needs a new cord/plug.   Given its a cheap tool, I'd suggest you try to fix it properly (for the learning experience), and if that doesn't work then you needed a replacement tool anyway.   And figure a better way to route the cord on the chopstand for next time.

Comment: "It works" is not the same as "Is it safe". The fact that it works means it can kill you. It can burst in flames from localized heating, or electrocute you. You're playing with electricity, and electricity by itself is already dangerous, and you're now combining it with a power tool that can sever limbs. Just think about that for a second. If the wire sparks and causes you to flinch into the blade, you just won a trip to the ER at minimum, and leaving with some scarring if you're lucky.

Answer (score 3):

If you would rather not go through the hassle of disassembling the grinder to replace the cord than cut cleanly through cord in two places to fully remove the mangled section of the cord.

Purchase a repair plug (male-type)[image]

Your cord is most likely 2 wire so you wont need a 3 prong plug. A 2 prong will suffice.

Comment: Given its a hand tool, the flex-cable is probably only 6 foot/2 metres long.  Making the off-cut into a short extension cable is probably not that useful.